# Possible to use SaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum and still maintain 3.0 backward compatibility?

Tags: iphone, compatibility

The function SaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum is only available with the iPhone SDK 3.1 or above but we want to maintain backward compatibility with 3.0 devices. How can this be done?

At first we though we can do a runtime check, but it turns out that this can't even compile against the 3.0 SDK.

We are getting the error

```
"_UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum", referenced from:    

-[MovieViewController saveButtonPressed:] in MovieViewController.o    

ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Base SDK to iPhone Device 3.0 (found inside Properties for the Project), and set the Active SDK to the latest version you're writing for.  This will cause the build to link to those methods that are not available weakly.  Just make sure you only call them in the versions of the OS where they are available.